# Como alterar a href por select e onchange usando javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Meu código é para alterar a url do `'href'` toda vez que o usuário alterar a select.
Eu fiz uma vez para alterar a `'src'` de uma imagem, mas quando usei `href` simplesmente não deu certo!

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function edit_music()
  {
    if (document.getElementById(\'select1\').value == "0") {
      document.preview1.style.visibility = "hidden";
      document.getElementById(\'random1\').style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
      var selected = document.getElementById(\'select1\').options[document.getElementById(\'select1\').selectedIndex].value;
      document.preview1.style.visibility = "visible";
      document.preview1.href = "vinhetas/"+selected;
      document.getElementById(\'random1\').style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Html:

```
<select id='select1' name='vinhetas' onchange='edit_music()'>
<option value='$arquivos'>".$arquivos."</option>
</select>
<a href="" name="preview1" id="preview1">Pré-ouvir</a>
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui amigos!
Fiz algo básico:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){

        mudaLink();
    }

    function mudaLink(){

             var selected  = document.getElementById(\'lista\').value
             document.getElementById(\'link-musical\').href = "vinhetas/"+selected+"";

                }
</script>
```

e no HTML apliquei:

```
<select id=\"lista\" onchange=\"return mudaLink();\" name='vinhetas'>
<option value='$arquivos'>".$arquivos."</option>
</select>
<a id="link-musical" href="teste.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" />Link</a>
```